# How can I highlight a selected row in a DataTable using React and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the datatable together with react and I would like it to be selected by clicking on a row of the table.
Using simple html and jquery, just using "select : true" in the parameters of the datatable instead in the code does not work, and from the checks it seems that the whole datatable is selected

```
export function gSearch() {

$('#list').dataTable().fnClearTable();
$('#list').dataTable().fnDestroy();
$("#list").show();

var bean = {
    gioco: $("#gioco").val(),
    famiglia: $("#famiglia").val(),
}

var urlServiceCriteria = SERVEREP +ricercaGameCriteria;

action(urlServiceCriteria, bean, functionCallBack, 'Error' + urlServiceCriteria, 'POST', 'json', true, null, false, true);
} 


function functionCallBack(data, extraParams) {

    if (data.success) {
        table = $('#' + list).DataTable({
            'responsive': true,
            data: data.data,
            columns: [
                {
                    className: 'dt-control',
                    orderable: false,
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: '',
                },
                { data: 'gio_id', "title": "gio_id" },
                { data: 'fgio_id', "title": "fgio_id" },
                {
                    data: 'gioco',
                    "title": "gioco"
                },
                { data: 'famiglia', "title": "famiglia" },
                { data: 'gg_descrizione', "title": "gg_descrizione" },
                { data: 'gio_id_provider', "title": "gio_id_provider" },
                { data: 'gio_cod_provider', "title": "gio_cod_provider" },
                { data: 'gio_num_linee', "title": "gio_num_linee" },
                { data: 'gio_rtp', "title": "gio_rtp" },
                { data: 'nome_pacchetto', "title": "nome_pacchetto" },
                { data: 'urlimg',
                    "title": "urlimg",
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return type === 'display'
                            ? '<input type=\'image\' src="' + data + '" width="48" height="48"></input>'
                            : data;
                    },

                },
                { data: 'prg_id', "title": 'prg_id' },
            ],
            select:true
        });

    } else {
        alert('error:' + data.message);
        /* toastr.error('error:'+data.message); */
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't react code